# How to update xml element in clob oracle having no root element

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I wanted to update a particular xml element value in a clob column in oracle .
The xml is as below

```
<TraceOn>NO</TraceOn>
<isDateTimePopulated>NO</isDateTimePopulated>
<serviceProvider>LWS</serviceProvider>
<AutomatedRetry>YES</AutomatedRetry>
<retryDateTime>2018-08-29-18.15.07</retryDateTime>
```

This data has no root element and i tried below query to update retryDateTime  but it doesn't work.

```
update READ_DATA p1 
set p1.bo_data = to_clob(updatexml(xmltype(p1.bo_data),
                 '/retryDateTime/text()','2018-08-29-18.15.07') )
 where INIT_MSRMT_DATA_ID='57610034614521';
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Make xml well formed by adding root node.

2) use xquery to update node (updatexml is deprecated)

3) return only root's childs

```
select xmlserialize(content xmlquery( 'copy $tmp := $xml_data modify 
    (for $i in $tmp/root/retryDateTime
               return replace value of node $i with $value)
               return $tmp/root/*'
passing  xmltype('<root>'||'<TraceOn>NO</TraceOn>
<isDateTimePopulated>NO</isDateTimePopulated>
<serviceProvider>LWS</serviceProvider>
<AutomatedRetry>YES</AutomatedRetry>
<retryDateTime>2018-08-29-18.15.07</retryDateTime>'||'</root>') as "xml_data", 'new node value' as "value" returning content) as clob indent size = 2)  from dual;
```

Usefull examples https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/app_depr_upd.htm#ADXDB6044

Comment: Damn.. you're fast :)

Comment: @Arkadiusz ... Using the given SQL i am able to update the xml element. Thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Most XML-Functions need to be used in SQL not plsql.

Here a Step-by-Step:

```
DECLARE
    myClob   VARCHAR2 (4000) := '<TraceOn>NO</TraceOn>
<isDateTimePopulated>NO</isDateTimePopulated>
<serviceProvider>LWS</serviceProvider>
<AutomatedRetry>YES</AutomatedRetry>
<retryDateTime>2018-08-29-18.15.07</retryDateTime>';

    myXml    XMLTYPE;
    tmp      VARCHAR2 (4000);
    tmpDate  Date;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' - - - build valid xml, by adding a root - - - ');
    myXml := XMLTYPE.CREATEXML ('<faketag>' || myClob || '</faketag>');

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (myXml.getClobVal ());

    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' - - - extract the desired tag - - - ');

    SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (myXml, '/faketag/retryDateTime') INTO tmp FROM DUAL; -- EXTRACTVALUE is ONLY allowed in SQL not PL/SQL! We need a select-into
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (tmp);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' - - - Extract the date to check the value and work with it - - - ');

    tmpDate := to_date(tmp,'yyyy-mm-dd-HH24.MI.SS');
    dbms_output.put_line('MyDate: ' || tmpDate); 

    dbms_output.put_line(' - - - update our xml - - - ');
    select updateXML(myXml, '/faketag/retryDateTime', '2017-01-01-13.59.59') into myXml from dual; -- updateXML is ONLY allowed in SQL not PL/SQL! We need a select-into
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (myXml.getClobVal ());

    dbms_output.put_line(' - - - now it''s you turn ;) - - - '); 
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried executing your code it worked fine for me with little correction in below line.                                                            select updateXML(myXml, '/faketag/retryDateTime', '2017-01-01-13.59.59') into myXml from dual; ----                                                         correction done -- '/faketag/retryDateTime/text()'

Comment: Hmm... working on my 12c db with and without `/test()`. What are u running on?